# How to make clickable Hexagon tiles in libGDX?

Tags: libgdx, hexagonal-tiles

I have a Hexagon tmx map in libGDX. The rendering works just fine, however I am having trouble finding out a way to detect clicks within these tiles.

Comment: It's not libGDX specific but I believe http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#pixel-to-hex answers your question very well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LibGDX: How to make tiled map tiles clickable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080272/libgdx-how-to-make-tiled-map-tiles-clickable)