# How to get tile position on touching it in isometric libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, tile, isometric

I'm creating 2d game,  it's just an isometric map in libgdx it's 64x32

```
   public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor
{


    public static float zoom=0.3f;
    Texture img;
    TiledMap tiledMap;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    TiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;
    final Matrix4 matrix = new Matrix4();
    public static float lastx,lasty;
    private IsometricTiledMapRenderer renderer;
    SpriteBatch sb;
    Texture texture;
    Sprite sprite;


    TextureRegion textureRegion;

    public static float translate,pick;

    float mapWidth;
    float mapHeight;
    static String c;
    TiledMapTileLayer.Cell cell;
    TiledMapTileLayer tileLayer;

    private Matrix4 isoTransform;

    private Matrix4 invIsotransform;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false,w,h);
        tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("iso.tmx");//iso
        renderer = new IsometricTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());


        isoTransform = new Matrix4();
        isoTransform.idt();
        isoTransform.translate(0.0f, 0.25f, 0.0f);
        isoTransform.scale((float)(Math.sqrt(2.0) / 2.0), (float)(Math.sqrt(2.0) / 4.0), 1.0f);
        isoTransform.rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -45.0f);

        //... and the inverse matrix
        invIsotransform = new Matrix4(isoTransform);
        invIsotransform.inv();

        camera.update();


        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

        sb = new SpriteBatch();
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("sand_128x64.png"));
        sprite = new Sprite(texture);
        sprite.setSize(50,50);



         mapWidth = tiledMap.getProperties().get("width",Integer.class);
         mapHeight = tiledMap.getProperties().get("height",Integer.class);



    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.5f, .7f, .9f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.zoom = zoom;




        camera.update();
        renderer.setView(camera);
        renderer.render();

        sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        sb.begin();
        //sprite.draw(sb);

        sb.end();



    }


    public Vector2 worldToCell(float x, float y) {
        float halfTileWidth = mapWidth * 0.5f;
        float halfTileHeight = mapHeight * 0.5f;

        float row = (1.0f/2) * (x/halfTileWidth + y/halfTileHeight);
        float col = (1.0f/2) * (x/halfTileWidth - y/halfTileHeight);

        return  new Vector2((int)col,(int)row);
    }

    public Vector2 screenToWorld(float x, float y){
        Vector3 touch = new Vector3(x,y,0);
        camera.unproject(touch);
        touch.mul(invIsotransform);
        touch.mul(isoTransform);
        return  new Vector2(touch.x,touch.y);
    }


    public Vector2 screenToCell(float x, float y) {
        Vector2 world = screenToWorld(x,y);
        world.y -= mapHeight *0.5f;
        return worldToCell(world.x,world.y);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        Vector2 cell = screenToCell(screenX,screenY);

        TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer)tiledMap.getLayers().get("Layer1");

        TiledMapTileLayer.Cell tileCell = layer.getCell((int) cell.x, (int) cell.y);
        TiledMapTile  tile = tileCell.getTile();

        tileCell.setFlipHorizontally(!tileCell.getFlipHorizontally());

        System.out.println("selectedCell = "+cell.toString());
        c=cell.toString();
        tileCell.setTile(tile);



        lastx=-screenX;
        lasty=screenY;
        Vector3 clickCoordinates = new Vector3(screenX,screenY,0);
        Vector3 position = camera.unproject(clickCoordinates);

        translate=position.x;



        return true;
    }





    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        lastx=0;
        lasty=0;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {

        if (lastx != 0) {
            camera.translate(-screenX - lastx, screenY - lasty);
            lastx = -screenX;
            lasty = screenY;




        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int p1)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int p1)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char p1)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        return false;
    }

}
```

And now I want to pick the tile on touching it,  so I get the tile (x,  y)  , I tried many ways to do this but I couldn't find a good solution,  and I tried this

[LibGDX: How to make tiled map tiles clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24080272/12421324)

But it didn't work,  so what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't put clickable squares as isometric maps are rotated squares

See [this](http://clintbellanger.net/articles/isometric_math/) article.
Or you can use a rotated matrix...

In `create` init the Matrixes...

```
    @Override
    public void create () {
        //create the isometric transform
        isoTransform = new Matrix4();
        isoTransform.idt();
        isoTransform.translate(0.0f, 0.25f, 0.0f);
        isoTransform.scale((float)(Math.sqrt(2.0) / 2.0), (float)(Math.sqrt(2.0) / 4.0), 1.0f);
        isoTransform.rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -45.0f);

        //... and the inverse matrix
        invIsotransform = new Matrix4(isoTransform);
        invIsotransform.inv();
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...

    }
```

Add this methods....

```
    public Vector2 worldToCell(float x, float y) {
        float halfTileWidth = TILE_WIDTH * 0.5f;
        float halfTileHeight = TILE_HEIGHT * 0.5f;

        float row = (1.0f/2) * (x/halfTileWidth + y/halfTileHeight);
        float col = (1.0f/2) * (x/halfTileWidth - y/halfTileHeight);

        return  new Vector2((int)col,(int)row);
    }

    public Vector2 screenToWorld(float x, float y){
        Vector3 touch = new Vector3(x,y,0);
        cam.unproject(touch);
        touch.mul(invIsotransform);
        touch.mul(isoTransform);
        return  new Vector2(touch.x,touch.y);
    }


    public Vector2 screenToCell(float x, float y) {
        Vector2 world = screenToWorld(x,y);
        world.y -= TILE_HEIGHT *0.5f;
        return worldToCell(world.x,world.y);
    }
```

And finally you would get the tile like this....

```
@Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        Vector2 cell = screenToCell(screenX,screenY);
        System.out.println("selectedCell = "+cell.toString());

        //if you want to get the tile and the cell 
        TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer)tiledMap.getLayers().get("Tile Layer 1");

        TiledMapTileLayer.Cell tileCell = layer.getCell((int) cell.x, (int) cell.y);
        TiledMapTile           tile     =  tileCell.getTile();

        //flip the tile just so you have a visual to make sure your selected the right tile
        tileCell.setFlipHorizontally(!tileCell.getFlipHorizontally());

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: My map is tmx file so it doesn't need to be rotate, and it show like this https://www.google.com/search?q=isometric+map&client=ms-opera-mobile&channel=new&espv=1&prmd=ivmn&sxsrf=ACYBGNSNzOQpp89PZ1Yjw39HXqxX7JtJ3w:1576661698280&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiau9PD8r7mAhUD6OAKHXIBBrsQ_AUoAXoECA0QAQ&biw=360&bih=472&dpr=2#imgrc=IJEOcaUqisYADM&imgdii=BrY3ho-vZ_XYaM. But I can't pick tile position by touching it

Comment: I know its a tmx , yes IT does you are rotating a matrix to match the map not the map itself

Comment: It crashed and give me this,,TiledMapTileLayer$Cell com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTileLayer.getCell(int, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: thats because the layer is null, replace `Tile Layer 1` with your TiledMap layer name

Comment: it work, but there are a small problem, so when I click (0.0) or (1.0)tile it's true , but when I touch another tile like (3.3) it give me the tile (2.2) and when I touch the tile (15.15) it give me another tile for example (6.6) , so when I touch any tile in the map it give me another tile on the same line except (0.0) and (1.0) it give me the real tile .

Comment: Is the correct tile flipping? Remember that libgdx 0,0 is bottom left while in Tiled 0,0 is top left

Comment: My map is bottom left and I know that the (0.0) is the tile which is in the bottom left so when I touch it,  it give me (0.0) and when I touch the second tile it give me (0.1) but the other tiles are wrong,  I can send the project to you if you want.

Comment: How would you do that? Update the question and put the code, verify that your variables TILE_WIDTH and TILE_HEIGHT ARE CORRECT

Comment: Now, I updated the question you can see the code now, I get the width and height by this code  mapWidth = tiledMap.getProperties().get("width",Integer.class); mapHeight = tiledMap.getProperties().get("height",Integer.class);

Comment: You are getting the `mapHeight` and `mapWidth` and you should get the `tileHeight` and the `tileWidth `

Comment: you can just modify `tiledMap.getProperties().get("width",Integer.class);` to `tiledMap.getProperties().get("tilewidth",Integer.class);` same for height and then rename the variables